# how to manage horizotal and vertical scrollbar in selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add horizontal scroll bar in select box.i have tried with div section with following code sample,but

```
 <div id="topicsInterest_id" style="width:180px;height:280px;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;">

            <select id="topicsinterest" name="topicsinterest" multiple="multiple" style="width:400px;height:270px;" class="inputtxtbox">
             <option> ...</option>
            </select>
 </div>
```

but client said that scroll box on the topic list etc the vertical scroller..is out of sight? It should be in view on the right side..

please help how to manage vertical scroll with horizontal scroll bar  in select box,something like this [image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;` to `<select>`? However, I'd recommend you to post some pictures of how you need to make the layout.

Comment: I tried with but it doesn't work with me.

Comment: "how to manage vertical scroll with horizontal scroll bar in select box" this sentence doesn't make sense to me. You want to get rid of scrollbars in select and just rely on scrollbars of div? Is that what you need?

Comment: I want to rely on scroll bars of div ,but problem is select box,also have vertical scroll-bar,if i used div vertical scroll bar then no sense to use select vertical scroll,if u suggest how to remove select scroll bar then my problem will solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this [demo](http://jsbin.com/iguqif/1/edit)

You just need to remove `overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;` and set it to

```
overflow:auto;   // show Scroll when Required`
```

OR

```
overflow:scroll;  //if you want to show scroll always
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `overflow-y: hidden;`, which specifies exactly the displayed behaviour (don't show vertical scrollbar).

If you set `overflow-y: scroll;` it will be visible.